# How to draw line with mousemove event in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events, web

I am working on draw line with jquery, it is working fine for me, but issue is line is only visible when i do `mouseup` event, what i want to do when i do `mousemove` event, it line should have to be grow up, can anyone please help me how can i do this ? I have added my script here, just want to do with `mousemove` event, I want to do this with only jquery i don't want canvas, can anyone please help me for this ? thanks for your time

```js
var coordinate = [];
            var count_line = 1;
            $("div").mousedown(function (event) {
  if(!$(event.target).hasClass('line')) {
      var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
      var relX = event.pageX - parentOffset.left;
      var relY = event.pageY - parentOffset.top;
      var temp_array = [];
      temp_array['X'] = (event.pageX - $(this).offset().left);
      temp_array['Y'] = event.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
      coordinate.push(temp_array);
  }
                
            });

            $("div").mouseup(function (event) {
  if(!$(event.target).hasClass('line')) {
      var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
      var relX = event.pageX - parentOffset.left;
      var relY = event.pageY - parentOffset.top;
      var temp_array = [];
      temp_array['X'] = (event.pageX - $(this).offset().left);
      temp_array['Y'] = event.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
      coordinate.push(temp_array);
      drawLine();
      coordinate = [];
      count_line++;
      $(".line").draggable();
  }
            });

            function drawLine() {
                console.log(coordinate);
                if (coordinate.length > 1)
                {
                    var start_x = coordinate[0]['X'];
                    var start_y = coordinate[0]['Y'];
                    var end_x = coordinate[1]['X'];
                    var end_y = coordinate[1]['Y'];
                    var x_diff = Math.abs(parseInt(end_x) - parseInt(start_x));
                    var y_diff = Math.abs(parseInt(end_y) - parseInt(start_y));
                    console.log(x_diff + ' - ' + y_diff);
                    if (x_diff > y_diff)
                    {
                        if (start_x < end_x) {
                            var width = parseInt(end_x) - parseInt(start_x);
                            $(".center-div").append("<div class='line' draggable='true' id='line_" + count_line + "' />");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("position", "absolute");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("left", start_x + "px");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("top", end_y + "px");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("width", width + "px");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("border", "1px solid black");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("height", "0px");
                        } else if (start_x > end_x) {
                            var width = parseInt(start_x) - parseInt(end_x);
                            $(".center-div").append("<div class='line' draggable='true' id='line_" + count_line + "' />");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("position", "absolute");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("left", end_x + "px");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("top", end_y + "px");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("width", width + "px");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("border", "1px solid black");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("height", "0px");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (start_y < end_y) {
                            var height = parseInt(end_y) - parseInt(start_y);
                            $(".center-div").append("<div class='line' draggable='true' id='line_" + count_line + "' />");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("position", "absolute");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("top", start_y + "px");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("left", start_x + "px");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("height", height + "px");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("width", "0px");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("border", "1px solid black");
                        } else if (start_y > end_y) {
                            var height = parseInt(start_y) - parseInt(end_y);
                            $(".center-div").append("<div class='line' draggable='true' id='line_" + count_line + "' />");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("position", "absolute");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("top", end_y + "px");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("left", start_x + "px");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("height", height + "px");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("width", "0px");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("border", "1px solid black");
                        }
                    }
                    coordinate = [];
                }
            }

            $("div").mousemove(function (event) {
  
            });
```

```css
.center-div {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;  
  background: grey;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
     }

            .line{
                height: 47px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid black;
                position: absolute;
            }
     .line:hover {
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  background: white;
  padding: 2px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
     }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="center-div"></div>
```

Comment: you need to use canvas...

Comment: @Wils i don't want to use canvas, i need to do with only jquery

Comment: So you want to create one div for every stroke? explain further

Comment: We need to increate div height something like that on mousemove so it can be grow

Comment: You got option 1, you create div as dot, the primitive element, or option 2, you create a longer stroke with css transform to set the rotation. How fine are you expecting the drawing?

Comment: so you want to draw many rectangles?

Comment: I want to draw either horizontal or vertical line

Comment: so you want a preview of the line during mouse move, am I getting it right?

Comment: Yes perfect. i want to do like that

Answer (score 0):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var drawx=0;
var drawy=0;


    $(document).mousemove(function(event){
        $("span").text(event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY);
        
    

 
});

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
          x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
          y: evt.clientY - rect.top
        };
      }
   
      canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
        var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
        var message = 'Mouse position: ' + mousePos.x + ',' + mousePos.y;
       if (drawx==0 && drawy==0) {
       drawx=mousePos.x;
drawy=mousePos.y;
       }
           ctx.moveTo(drawx,drawy);
ctx.lineTo(mousePos.x,mousePos.y);
ctx.stroke();

drawx=mousePos.x;
drawy=mousePos.y;
       
      }, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>


<span></span>
```

See my snipper on canvas drawing.
Div element is not designed for drawing and it will bring performance and memory issues.

Comment: sorry, bro I don't need canvas, i want to do with jquery only

Answer (score 0):

Finally i resolved it

```js
            var coordinate = [];
            var count_line = 1;
            var starting_coordinate_x = '';
            var starting_coordinate_y = '';
            var is_clicked = false;
            $("div").mousedown(function (event) {
                if (!$(event.target).hasClass('line')) {
                    var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
                    var relX = event.pageX - parentOffset.left;
                    var relY = event.pageY - parentOffset.top;
                    var temp_array = [];
                    temp_array['X'] = (event.pageX - $(this).offset().left);
                    temp_array['Y'] = event.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
                    starting_coordinate_x = temp_array['X'];
                    starting_coordinate_y = temp_array['Y'];
                    coordinate.push(temp_array);
                    is_clicked = true;
                    $(".center-div").append("<div class='line' id='line_" + count_line + "' />");
                }
            });

            $("div").mouseup(function (event) {
                coordinate = [];
                count_line++;
                is_clicked = false;
                $(".line").draggable();
            });

            function drawLine(starting_coordinate_x, starting_coordinate_y, end_coordinate_x, end_coordinate_y) {
                console.log(coordinate);
                if (coordinate.length > 1)
                {
                    var start_x = starting_coordinate_x;
                    var start_y = starting_coordinate_y;
                    var end_x = end_coordinate_x;
                    var end_y = end_coordinate_y;
                    var x_diff = Math.abs(parseInt(end_x) - parseInt(start_x));
                    var y_diff = Math.abs(parseInt(end_y) - parseInt(start_y));
                    console.log(x_diff + ' - ' + y_diff);
                    if (x_diff > y_diff)
                    {
                        if (start_x < end_x) {
                            var width = parseInt(end_x) - parseInt(start_x);
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("position", "absolute");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("left", start_x + "px");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("top", end_y + "px");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("width", width + "px");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("border", "1px solid black");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("height", "0px");
                        } else if (start_x > end_x) {
                            var width = parseInt(start_x) - parseInt(end_x);
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("position", "absolute");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("left", end_x + "px");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("top", end_y + "px");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("width", width + "px");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("border", "1px solid black");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("height", "0px");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (start_y < end_y) {
                            var height = parseInt(end_y) - parseInt(start_y);
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("position", "absolute");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("top", start_y + "px");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("left", start_x + "px");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("height", height + "px");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("width", "0px");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("border", "1px solid black");
                        } else if (start_y > end_y) {
                            var height = parseInt(start_y) - parseInt(end_y);
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("position", "absolute");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("top", end_y + "px");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("left", start_x + "px");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("height", height + "px");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("width", "0px");
                            $("div #line_" + count_line).css("border", "1px solid black");
                        }
                    }
                    coordinate = [];
                }
            }

            $("div").mousemove(function (event) {
                if (is_clicked) {
                    var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
                    var relX = event.pageX - parentOffset.left;
                    var relY = event.pageY - parentOffset.top;
                    var temp_array = [];
                    temp_array['X'] = (event.pageX - $(this).offset().left);
                    temp_array['Y'] = (event.pageY - $(this).offset().top);
                    console.log(temp_array['X'], temp_array['Y']);
                    coordinate.push(temp_array);
                    drawLine(starting_coordinate_x, starting_coordinate_y, temp_array['X'], temp_array['Y']);
                }
            });
```

```css
     .center-div {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;  
  background: grey;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
     }

            .line{
                height: 47px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid black;
                position: absolute;
            }
     .line:hover {
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  background: white;
  padding: 2px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
     }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="center-div"></div>
```